# Stuff with group by on DATENAME function

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Situation:

Let there be a table `ALPHA` which contains a column `ALPHA.ID_BETA` (Foreign Key on Table `BETA`) and a column `ALPHA.CREATIONDATE (DATETIME NOT NULL)`.

Now assume the following records in Table `ALPHA`:

| ID | CREATIONDATE (YYYY-MM-DD) | ID_BETA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-26 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-02-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |

Now imagine Table `BETA` to look like this (i left out other columns for simplicity:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |

Desired Output:
Is a value that concatenates all values (Format: DATENAME + YYYY) of `CREATIONDATE` for a single `ID_BETA` Ordered by date ascending. In this example, the output should be `January 2022, February 2022, May 2022` (obviously depending on Language settings)

What I have tried:

```
SELECT STUFF(
               (SELECT ', ' 
+ DATENAME(MONTH,(ALPHA.CREATIONDATE)) + DATENAME(YEAR, ALPHA.CREATIONDATE)
                FROM ALPHA
                WHERE ALPHA.ID_BETA = 1
                GROUP BY ALPHA.CREATIONDATE
                ORDER BY ALPHA.CREATIONDATE ASC
                FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')
```

This however will not give me distinct values. Trying out the obvious `DISTINCT` statement gives me the following error:

> Server: Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Note that I cannot solve this problem with the "new" [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function since it's only supported from SQL-Server2017 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group and sort by `EOMONTH(CREATIONDATE)` in order to group by a single date per month, rather than grouping just by `CREATIONDATE`.

> Note also that you need `.value` to unescape the XML, and the third parameter of `STUFF` should be the same as the length of the separator

```sql
SELECT STUFF(
               (SELECT
                  ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)) + DATENAME(YEAR, EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE))
                FROM ALPHA a
                WHERE a.ID_BETA = 1
                GROUP BY
                  EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)
                ORDER BY
                  EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(', '), '')
```

If you want to do this per row of `BETA` you can use `CROSS APPLY` or a subquery:

```sql
SELECT STUFF(
               (SELECT
                  ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH, EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)) + DATENAME(YEAR, EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE))
                FROM ALPHA a
                WHERE a.ID_BETA = b.ID
                GROUP BY
                  EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)
                ORDER BY
                  EOMONTH(a.CREATIONDATE)
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
           ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(', '), '')

FROM BETA b;
```

Comment: This orders the results correctly by year but the months are ordered by name instead of chronological order. I may have not defined the requirement thoroughly enough. (So right now I get results like `April, August, December, February, January` instead of `January, February, April, August, December`

Comment: Hmm, you're right, you need to use `EOMONTH`

Answer (score 1):

As an error mesage says, order by exactly the expression in the select clause

```
       SELECT STUFF(
           (SELECT distinct ', ' 
  + DATENAME(MONTH,(ALPHA.CREATIONDATE)) + DATENAME(YEAR, ALPHA.CREATIONDATE)
            FROM ALPHA
            WHERE ALPHA.ID_BETA = 1
            GROUP BY ALPHA.CREATIONDATE
            ORDER BY ', ' 
  + DATENAME(MONTH,(ALPHA.CREATIONDATE)) + DATENAME(YEAR, ALPHA.CREATIONDATE) ASC
            FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Taking a whole list of dates ranging from 01.01.2018 to 31.12.2021 into account: The result as desired would be `January 2018, February 2018, March 2018, ... January 2019`. Instead i get `April 2018, April 2019, ... August 2018, August 2019`. So right now the ordering is done by name of month instead of chronological order of the month. Please forgive me for not defining it not detailed enough.